# Replacing the value of blade foreach loop using Fetch Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'm trying to add a live search in my project. searching the specified icons data when the key pressed trigger the ajax request.

But the problem is I'm trying to reuse the table which is already use for placing the icons data using foreach. I get the data from a specific method in my controller. I need to replace the foreach data to placing ajax request data when key pressed to the same table.

The code is below

```
public function index()
{   
    $poseicons = Poseicon::paginate(5);
    return view('config.config',['poseicons' => $poseicons]
    );
}

public function search($request){
    $poseicons = Poseicon::where('icons_id','%'.$request.'%')
    ->orwhere('name','%'.$request.'%')
    ->orwhere('icons','%'.$request.'%')
    ->get();
    return $poseicons;
}
```

then this the is the table

```
   <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Icon</th>
            <th scope="col">Action</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach($poseicons as $poseicon)
                <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{$loop->iteration}}</th>
                <td>{{$poseicon->icons_id}}</td>
                <td>{{$poseicon->name}}</td>
                <td><a href="/poseicon/{{$poseicon->icons_id}}" class="badge bg-info rounded-pill">Detail</a></td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
    </table>
```

then the ajax request

```
    function fetchIconsSearch(){
    let token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');
    let search = document.getElementById('icons').value;
    const url = `/metadata/search/${search}`;
                  fetch(url,
                    {
                        headers: {
                            "Content-Type": "application/json",
                            "Accept": "application/json, text-plain, */*",
                            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
                            "X-CSRF-TOKEN": token,
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*", 
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true  
                            },
                        method: 'get',
                        credentials: "same-origin"
                    })
                    .then(response => response.json()).then(response =>{
                            console.log(response);
                            //should i do foreach here then replace the value of the table?
                            //already try inserting data to the table. but the data become very messy because of the foreach.
                        }    
                    )
}
```

So the conclusion is I want to know this is possible to do with plain-vanilla javascript and laravel.

If it's not possible please give me any alternative way to resolve this problem.

Thank you, I'm very sorry about my very bad English, I hope this conveyed.

Note: the ajax request work properly.

Comment: So you need to replace the rows in the table by a new collection that you get using ajax?

Comment: yes,  replacing the rows by the data from ajax request.

Comment: there are multiple ways of doing that, i personally would return a view with the contents of tbody in the ajax call and replace the innerHTML of tbody. But you can also empty the tbody and add your tr's in a javascript loop

Comment: so i need to rewrite the table from tbody using innerHTML. and loop the data from ajax request?

Comment: but how to get back the old data when the search input is null.

Comment: You could check if the return is null, and only replace it if there is data.

Comment: Thanks for the help sir, i appreciate you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227840/discussion-between-shinichirou-ikebe-and-gert-b).